# Call JQuery Validate Plugin without submitting the form

Tags: jquery, plugins, jquery-validate, submit

Is it possible to validate the form without submitting it using the JQuery  validation plugin?

I use a button.click function for validating, the button isn't a submit input.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to test the form's validity without submitting it.

[See `.valid()` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/valid/).

Whenever `.valid()` is called the form is tested, and the method will also return a boolean.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#myform').validate({ // initialize the plugin
        // rules & options
    });

    $('#button').click(function() {
        if ($('#myform').valid()) {
            alert('form is valid - not submitted');
        } else {
            alert('form is not valid');
        }
    });

});
```

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/zMYVq/**

Comment: Thank you. And can you please tell me how do I make All inputs and textfields required ? without specifying each field in the rules by name.. I thought $('#myform').validate() does that but it doesn't, when I use it without rules.. the form is always valid even if it's not!

Comment: never mind.. I found the solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9504382/jquery-validator-plug-in-trigger-from-within-a-function , I should've put $('#myform').validate() in the Ajax callback function since the form is loaded dynamically.