# jQuery Validate() and Valid() methods undefined or do not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation

I use jQuery validation in my MVC4 project with the necessary javascript files (**jquery-1.9.1.js**, **jquery.validate.min.js** and **jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js**) and configuration. What I want to do is to validate the form before submitting it. If the form is valid, a method will be called and then it will be submitted. If not, it will not be submitted and simply an alert will be displayed. I have followed the steps on [Call JQuery Validate Plugin without submitting the form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16725414/call-jquery-validate-plugin-without-submitting-the-form) and lots of similar topics especially on the jQuery offical pages. But somehow, when executing the Validate() and Valid() method I encountered errors like undefined. I think the problem is related to Validate() method. I have tried different kind of jquery-1.x.x.js files, but the result is the same. How can I validate the form by using a similar method to the method below? Or anything else?

```
script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
        $("#submitbtn").click(function () {
            var form = $("#myForm");
            form.validate();
            var isValid = form.valid();

            if (isValid) { //If there is no validation error
                alert('form is valid - not submitted');
            } 
            else {
                alert('form is not valid');                               
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Are you getting the undefined errors on the validate() or valid() calls?

Comment: if possible can you create a demo jsfiddle for this ?

Comment: What is the exact error message you're getting?

Comment: @jaq316 : Here is the watch values on Firebug: http://i.stack.imgur.com/kJKxV.png

Comment: @Doktorn: In addition to the screenshot, the error is related to not finding a proper Valid() method or not executing the Validate() method.

Comment: @Rahul Gupta: Sorry, but I could not create jsfiddle as I have never used before. I tried, but I could not add external javascript files from my computer and I am not sure if there is a mistake on this. http://jsfiddle.net/SY65e/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot all of you. Finally I have managed to combine validation methods with the spinner example posted on: http://blog.tkglaser.net/2012/02/waiting-spinner-for-long-running-form.html

**View:**

```
<style type="text/css">
#loading {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
    z-index: 1000;
}

#loadingcontent {
    display: table;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#loadingspinner {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: larger;
    padding-top: 80px;
}
</style>


$(function () {        
    //Waiting spinner for long-running form submits using jQuery
    $("#submitbtn").click(function () {

        var form = $("#addForm");
        form.validate();

        if (form.valid()) {
            $("#loading").fadeIn();
            var opts = {
                lines: 12, // The number of lines to draw
                length: 7, // The length of each line
                width: 4, // The line thickness
                radius: 10, // The radius of the inner circle
                color: '#000', // #rgb or #rrggbb
                speed: 1, // Rounds per second
                trail: 60, // Afterglow percentage
                shadow: false, // Whether to render a shadow
                hwaccel: false // Whether to use hardware acceleration
            };
            var target = document.getElementById('loading');
            var spinner = new Spinner(opts).spin(target);
        }
    });
});


<div id="loading">
    <div id="loadingcontent">
        <p id="loadingspinner">
            Waiting...
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

I found the code was working perfectly fine however the ID of the element was not "myForm", have you tried ensuring that the ClientID attribute of the form is used rather than the ID?

```
$(function () {
    $("#submitbtn").click(function () {
        var form = $('#<%# myForm.ClientID %>');
        form.validate();
        var isValid = form.valid();
        if (isValid) { //If there is no validation error
            alert('form is valid - not submitted');
        } 
        else {
            alert('form is not valid');                               
        }
    });
});
```

I believe `$("#myForm")` wasn't returning the element as you would have expected (e.g. it was returning null or undefined as myForm didn't exist) hence form.validate() wouldn't exist.

Comment: I think you've used the wrong syntax, <%# ... code ... %> I believe is used for binding,  <%= ... code ... %> I believe to be the correct markup unless using Razor syntax (see: http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx)

Comment: @user2928044: I have tried to use '#myForm.ClientID' and '#<%# myForm.ClientID %>' instead of "#myForm" but it does not maka any sense. Still get the same errors form.validate() > undefined.

Comment: What's your markup, is there definitely an element with an ID (clientID or otherwise) of "myForm", I was working on the assumption that there was a form element with an ID of "myForm" which also has a `runat=server`. Also if you add `debugger;` you might be able to work out what is form is being set to.

Comment: It is related to validating the form at the same time with the help of jQuery Valid() and Validate() methods rather than validating each element seperately (I can already validate them seperately without any problem). You might see my code above and inform me if there is an error typing of the code.

Answer (score 0):

What is the exact error message you got? Maybe you are not referencing jquery properly.
Try do a simple jquery call like `alert($("#myInput").val());`

Comment: It is not validating any element on the form. It is an issue related to validating whole form at the same time with the help of jQuery Valid() and Validate() methods. You might see my code above and inform me if there is an error typing of the code.